# How to find the minutes and the seconds of an angle in sexagesimal units when a condition is given?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is as follows:

A certain angle $\alpha$ is measured by a goniometer in sexagesimal units. This results in $a^{\circ}b'c''$ assuming $\textrm{a, b, c} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq b < 60\,0\leq c < 60$ and the number of sexagesimal minutes plus the double of the number of its sexagesimal degrees equals to $155$, find $a+b+c$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{30}\\
2.&\textrm{32}\\
3.&\textrm{31}\\
4.&\textrm{60}\\
\end{array}$

How exactly should this question should be approached?. What I've attempted is to account from the condition this:

Since it mentions:

```
the number of sexagesimal minutes plus 
the double of the number of its 
sexagesimal degrees equals to 155
```

Then this is translated as follows:

$b+2a=155$

But from here its where I'm stuck. I do believe that you can put this as:

$155=2k+1$

Hence it would meant that $b$ might be $1^{\circ}$?

Upon further inspecting this I thought it could meant:

$2\left(a+\frac{b}{60}+\frac{c}{3600}\right)+b+\frac{c}{60}=155$

Which would become into:

$a+\frac{b}{30}+\frac{c}{1800}+b+\frac{c}{60}=155$

$\frac{1800a+60b+c+30b+30c}{1800}=155$

Then this becomes into:

$\frac{1800a+90b+31c}{1800}=155$

But as it can be seen there isn't a way to simplify this expression.

Can someone help me here?. What exactly should be the right approach?.

Comment: One equation and three unknowns makes this difficult. In particular $c$ seems able to take 60 different values. Is there more to the question?

Answer (score 1):

I've interpreted the phrase you pulled out as

$$2(a + \frac{b}{60}+\frac{c}{3600})+(60a+b+\frac{c}{3600})=155 $$
Which simplifies to
$$3600a+60b+c=9000$$
With 3 unknowns normally this couldn't be taken much further. But, there are restrictions on $a, b, c$, namely they must all be integers. $b, c$ have further restrictions. I am also assuming $a≥0$.
A quick calculation shows that $a$ can only be 0, 1, or 2.
If $a=0$ then $60b+c=9000$ which cannot be since $b$ and $c <60$
Similarly for $a=1$. $\therefore a=2$, $\therefore 60b+c=1800$
By following a similar process for $b$ it quickly becomes apparent that $b=30$, leaving $c=0$.
Hence $a+b+c=32$
Not a direct approach but without further information I'm not sure what else could be done.